# Yandex-tank - several requests with different http headers

Tags: testing, http-headers, load-testing, yandex, yandex-tank

Have anyone tried to use [Yandex-tank](https://github.com/yandex-load/yandex-tank) as http load testing tool?

I have a usecase to test a http service with multiple requests containing different path and query params and different http headear.

E.G. First request type - /test/user1?param1=1 [X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.0.1], second request type - /test/user2?param1=2 [X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.0.2]

And the problem is how to configure ammo.txt file to have different http headers.

I tried:

```
# load.conf    
[phantom]
address=myservice.loc #Target's address and port .
rps_schedule=line(1, 50, 1m) ## 1 minute, from 1 to 50 requests per second

# ammo.txt    
[X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.0.1]
/test/user1?param1=1    

[X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.0.2]
/test/user2?param1=2
```

Test performs ok but all the requestd have X-Forwarded-For: **192.168.0.1**

I wounder how to configure ammo.txt to fit my usecase (to have different headers)?
Also could you please suggest some alternative tool to do this?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can not have different headers when using URI format.</strike>

UPD: we added a new feature and now you can do that in uri-style ammo, see [docs](http://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#uri-style-uris-in-file). An example of a uri-style ammo with headers modification:

```
[Connection: close]
[Host: target.example.com]
[Cookies: None]
/?drg tag1
/
/buy tag2
[Cookies: test]
/buy/?rt=0&station_to=7&station_from=9
```

You also could generate ammo in request-style as described [here](http://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#request-style).
An example of request-style ammo with different 'Host' headers:

```
34 good
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: xxx.tanks1.example.com
User-Agent: xxx (shell 1)

78 bad
GET /abra HTTP/1.0
Host: xxx.tanks2.example.com
User-Agent: xxx (shell 1)

79 unknown
GET /ab/ra HTTP/1.0
Host: xxx.tanks3.example.com
User-Agent: xxx (shell 1)
```

`34 good` -- this is the header, the number is the size of the following request in bytes (including line endings). And `good` is a marker.

Comment: can you put some example here?